# FAQ not working on DNN 8.0.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have just upgraded a website from DNN version 6.1.3 to 8.0.0.

Post upgrade I found that the FAQ module had updates available as shown in this screen [image: Updates for FAQ]

I downloaded the latest available FAQ module(5.1.1) and installed on my website.

It seemed that the updates are installed successfully but FAQ module stopped rendering.

In the edit mode it displays following error message

DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost - System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnListBox'

I tried troubleshooting many ways but no luck.

Really appreciate if someone can help in this.

[image: FAQ error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to some of the Controls being moved to the DotNetNuke.Web.Deprecated DLL.

Here's a commit in the FAQ project which looks to correct this issue

https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.Faq/commit/0718e084be5c0dbdf1c085aa804a44cde8ab3037

Your best bet is to fork that project and compile it yourself to build a new ZIP version to use, or to wait for the project to complete a new release with the fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest version (5.3.0).  I had to contact support, but they sent me a copy of that version of the FAQ module today and it seems to work in DNN 8.3.0.